# Allow anonymous user to write to firebase firestore

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I want to allow links inside my application looking like:

`mywebsite.com?u=nc27ri3ucfyinyh3`

where `nc27ri3ucfyinyh3` is a uuid, so the link can be sent to an anonymous user. The anonymous user should be able to view the page (database read), but it should also log to the database that they've viewed that link (database write).

As we get a warning when our firestore rules look like

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write;
    }
  }
}
```

as it is not secure.

> Your security rules are defined as public, so anyone can steal, modify or delete data in your database

How should we handle the case of these anonymous users?

Answer (score 3):

The first thing is that you could write a more restrictive set of rules than you have there (for example, restrict writes to just one collection (by changing the `match /{document=**}` line to something more restrictive (e.g. just the `links` collection or something).  This, of course, still effectively allows anonymous users the full run of your database, but only within that collection.

Additionally, you can add [validation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-conditions#data_validation) to the incoming request via the `request.resource` object) -- its likely due to the anonymous nature of the user that you will still have a relatively insecure set of rules.

The data validation approach can look at both the current state of the database (in `resource.data`) as well as the contents of the incoming request (in `request.resource`).  Here is the reference documentation for [Resource](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.firestore.Resource) and [Request](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.firestore.Request) objects.

Here is an example rule that assumes these documents:

- Exist in the `/uuids` collection
- Are created by some other method (authenticated user, admin API, etc)
- Only need to be fetched by ID, not queried as a set.
- Only have 2 fields: `content` and `visits`
- `visits` must be an integer, and is only allowed to be incremented
- When the document is created, `visits` is initialized to zero.

I have not extensively tested these rules, only used the simulator to confirm they behave roughly as expected, I recommend you [write extensive tests](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/test-rules-emulator) for any rules you intend to deploy.  In particular, I am not certain about the behavior of the test for only being incremented when the document is under heavy contention.

```
rules_version = '2';

function notUpdating(field) {
     return !(field in request.resource.data)
      || resource.data[field] == request.resource.data[field]
}

service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /uuids/{uuidValue} {
      allow get: if true;
      allow update: if (request.resource.data.keys().size() == 2 &&
                        notUpdating('content') &&
                        request.resource.data['visits'] == int(request.resource.data['visits']) &&
                        request.resource.data['visits'] > 0 &&
                        request.resource.data['visits'] == resource.data['visits'] + 1);
      allow write: if false;  // these 4 lines can also just be omitted
      allow list: if false;
      allow delete: if false;
      allow create: if false;
    }
  }
}
```

This would allow you, for example, to ensure that only exactly the field you want is being touched, and only with valid data (e.g. positive integers or similar).

Remember -- the security rules are your *only* protection -- users can run arbitrary code against the database within those rules, not just code that you have given them.  So, for example, if they can blanket read the collection, they can literally read the entire set of documents in that collection.

---

Alternatively, it might instead make sense to write an http, https, or callable [cloud function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/http-events) that does exactly what you need -- register that the link has been used via a write, and then redirect or serve the necessary data itself.  This gives you a lot more control over the specific write, but it does come with some added cost.  The advantage here is that you wouldn't need to allow any public or open access to the database at all.

Cloud functions can also be served off of `mywebsite.com` if that web site is hosted on Firebase Hosting, via [rewrite rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/full-config#direct_requests_to_a_function).

Comment: Thank you for all the info! Would you be able to give an example of what the data validation approach would look like? Am I being silly in thinking that I could just have all of those routes authenticate with a known user that is fed from env variables and have that user be the only one that can write?

Comment: I have updated an example rule that demonstrates the technique, but I encourage you to test it extensively before using it.

Comment: Thank you for the help. This is my fault but I did not fully write the data that will be written to the database. It isn't a simple number for `viewCount`. It is a complex array of objects with information such as IP address, location, and a lot of other information about the user. Will this method still be the viable option?

Comment: It depends on the data, your rules will likely become very complicated very quickly though.  I'd strongly encourage you to look at a cloud function approach (either as a direct HTTP request, or by processing create events in a collection that is then cleaned up).

Comment: Is there a large security concern for the back-end to do `firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword('some-email@gmail.com', 'some-complex-password')` being populated from env variables, and then can use that `uid` in your firestore rules?

Comment: That's really a different question, but if you're using a backend, I'd recommend using the Admin SDK and a service account credential, not by trying to use a client SDK via firebase auth.